# Error message while uploading iOS app

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, nszombieenabled

I wanted to upload an iOS app, but I got this error:

> Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the errors,
>   correct them, and resubmit your application.  The app references
>   non-public symbols in xxx.app/xxx: NSZombieEnabled

I've searched the whole project for "nszombieneabled" and did not find it. What is the problem? Can anyone help me?

I build the App with Visual Studio 2012

Comment: check your build scheme, and disable zombie detection in "diagnostic" panel

Comment: Where can I find this in Visual Studio?

Comment: The same place you set it?

Comment: omg, missed you last line... is that possible to build iPhone app with Visual Studio? :)

Comment: Yes it is possible with a Xamarin plugin :)